# Vue3: slot inside iframe srcdoc?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

Is there a way to use a slot's content inside an iframe's `srcdoc` attribute?

**AppIframe.vue**

```
<template>
    // html...

    <iframe srcdoc="<slot></slot>"></iframe>

    // html...
</template>

<script>
    export default {};
</script>
```